# Pygame: Why is my circle not being drawn onto my sprite's surface?

Tags: pygame

This is probably so simple, but I cannot see my error. Why is my ball not being drawn onto my sprite's surface and thus not appearing on the screen? When I change the 'draw ellipse' line in the class so that it is drawn onto the screen (instead of onto the surface), it shows. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pygame

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """This class represents the ball."""
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """ Constructor. Pass in the balls x and y position. """
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
        # Create the surface, give dimensions and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        # Draw the ellipse onto the surface
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, (255,0,0), [0,0,width,height], 10)

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Events code goes here (mouse clicks, key hits etc)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # --- Clear the screen
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    # --- Draw all the objects
    ball = Ball(100,100)

    # --- Update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circle is drawn onto your sprite's surface, but you never draw the sprite onto the screen.

Also, you should probably only create one instance of `Ball`, not one on every iteration of your main loop.

You usually put your sprites into groups and call `draw` on those to actually draw the sprites, like

```
...
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# --- Create sprites and groups
ball = Ball(100,100)
g = pygame.sprite.Group(ball)

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Events code goes here (mouse clicks, key hits etc)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # --- Clear the screen
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    # --- Draw all the objects
    g.draw(screen)

    # --- Update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Note that your sprite needs also a `rect` attribute for this to work:

```
...
# Create the surface, give dimensions and set it to be transparent
self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
self.image.fill(WHITE)
self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
# this rect determinies the position the ball is drawn
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
# Draw the ellipse onto the surface
pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, (255,0,0), [0,0,width,height], 10)
...
```

Comment: This is great, but just so I understand this properly, say I didn't want to add this object to a group, how could I draw the surface? If I create the ball object outside the 'Main Loop', how do I get the surface drawn on each iteration?

Comment: If you don't want to use groups, you'll have to blit the sprite's image manually to the screen, like `ball.image.blit(screen, (0, 0))`

Comment: Thank you! Brilliant help. Very much appreciated!

Comment: self.image.fill(WHITE) and self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE) can be deleted !